# Strange string.Format behavior

Tags: c#, string.format

I've a `double` variable called `totalCost` and it's value is `1025`.
The result of calling a simple `string.Format` is the following:

```
?string.Format("{0}",totalCost)
"1,025"
```

My thousand separator is the dot while the decimal separator is the coma.

The weird part is the following:

```
?string.Format("{0:0.0}",totalCost)
"1,0"
```

Doesn't it should be `1025.0` (or `1,025.0`)?

It seems that it converts the double in a string (giving "1.025") and then re-parse it without using my separator settings (interpreting it as 1-and-25-thousandths) and finally it formats the converted value.

**EDIT**: the thread culture is:

```
?System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
{it-IT}
```

Comment: I've edited my question since I had typed the wrong separators

Comment: You sure the value is `1025`? both cases are suited to the value being `1.025` and your decimal separator being a comma

Comment: Can you check what your CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is? If you post it, we can recreate your scenario.

Comment: @nvoigt I've posted it

Comment: For me it outputs `1025,0` with culture `it-IT`

Comment: What format do you want to be output?

Comment: `string.Format("{0:0.0}",1025.0)` => `"1025,0"`

Comment: There has to be something other than just the culture impacting this as the output of that string.Format line here, with the Italian culture, gives me "1025", not "1,025". So culture alone cannot be responsible for this.

Comment: As Sriram, Tim and Myself have confirmed, the results you are getting should not be correct. Can you provide a full slice of code that can replicate the issue?

Comment: Shame on me.. I usually use different separator so I though 1,025 was 1025..it actually is 1.025..I'm sorry guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You scenario is not what you think it is. I am 100% sure that your real value of `totalCost` is actually `1.025` (one and twenty five thousandths), because this is the only value that will produce both the same results that you have given.

This can be seen with the following code:

```
double d = 1.025; 
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT"), "{0}",d));
//1,025
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT"), "{0:0.0}",d));
//1,0
```

As you can see, both outputs match with yours. I would suggest you use a debugger to step through the code and see at which point the value is being changed. (perhaps you are dividing by 1000 somewhere along the line)

**Direct Answer**: There is no strange behaviour, the code is working exactly as expected.

Comment: I agree with musefan. Here's a demo (http://ideone.com/cO2CaD) that validates his answer.

Comment: Shame on me.. I usually use different separator so I though 1,025 was 1025..it actually is 1.025